# Drupal Page template file for a view

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-views

I have a view called "video_by_category" with a path of "video/category/%" the % is looking for a taxonomy term. A term can be "car".
I want to create a custom page template for this view similar to page.tpl.php. I made some theme suggestions like page-video-category, page-video_by_category.tpl.php, page-views-view-video-category.tpl.php, but nothing is working. How can this be done?

In my template.php I have this:

```
function theme428_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['node']->type != "") {
    if (arg(0)=='node' && arg(2)!='edit') { // not for node edit forms
        if(arg(1)!=''){
            $arg1='-'.arg(1);
        }


        //$variables['template_files'][] = "page-node-" . $variables['node']->type.$arg1;
        $variables['template_files'][] = "page-node-" . $variables['node']->type;
    }


  }

    //print_r($variables['template_files']);
      $variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();  


  return $variables;

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the results of `page_manager_get_current_page()` in your preprocess to determine if you view is active.  You can then use `arg()` to get the term (it may also be in the handler info).  You can then either just tack on a new body class, or you can set your own template suggestion (http://drupal.org/node/223440), which you are doing already for something else.

Personally, I try to have a single page template for the whole site, and then do custom layouts with panels pages and custom panel layout templates.  I find using views as pages more trouble than they are worth.

Answer (score 0):

Views 1 used to have an automatic creator for this, but 2 doesn't... See [documentation](http://groups.drupal.org/node/10129)